# Twilio Notifications alert received when app in foreground

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, swift4, twilio-programmable-chat

I am using twilio push notifications in ios app. The problem is i am getting the notification alert in the foreground mode also. How it is possible as ios dont provide this.

And another issue is how can i set the title for the twilio push notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your bundle identifier in the twilio configuration setting. May be some character is not correctly placed.
Maybe you have configured alert , sound , badge functionality in notification delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

For any push notification in iOS, this is the structure ([developer.apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification)):

```
{
   “aps” : {
      “alert” : {
         “title” : “Title”,
         “subtitle” : “Subtitle”
         “body” : “Body!”,
      }
   }
}
```

And twilio it is not exception, you must configure your notification like show above, or there are some examples: 
[Just go to end of page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/api/notifications)

Comment: I can't configure notification in twilio. It is default from there end.